# FTP issue - VSFTPd and connecting to from FileZilla

Tags: linux, ftp, configuration, vsftpd

I'm trying to connect to a CentOS Linux box that I have hosted on EC2 and I think I have everything configured correctly but when I try to connect I get this series of messages

`Status:    Connection established, waiting for welcome message...

Response:   220 (vsFTPd 2.0.5)

Command:    USER tyndall
Response:   331 Please specify the password.

Command:    PASS *********

Response:   230 Login successful.

Status: Connected

Status: Retrieving directory listing...

Command:    PWD

Response:   257 "/home/tyndall"

Command:    TYPE I

Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.

Command:    PASV
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing`

Not sure where to start troubleshooting this issue. Any ideas?
Do I need to change any permissions? I would think this ID has the ability to see my own home directory.

I am able to push/pull files from the command line version of FTP client working on Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this exact problem on one of my servers in the past; It was a Filezilla server on Windows Server 2008 also on EC2.

The solution:
It was a matter of setting the passive port range on the ftp server & opening that same range in the EC2 Security Groups. You may even need to add the range to IPTables within CentOS if iptables is being used -- although you should consider turning off iptables as it is a bit redundant with EC2 Security Groups.

Have a look here: http://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=7315

[alt text][1] [1]:http://www.iainlbc.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/security_groups.png

You could also configure VSFTPd to use active (not passive) mode - so it uses only port 20/21. The difference between active and passive is explained here: http://www.slacksite.com/other/ftp.html

Comment: If I'm just using plain old FTP wouldn't I only need port 20 and 21 open? I'm adding this to the question, but I am able to push/pull files from the command line version of FTP client working on Windows.

Comment: In PASV move the client initiates both connections right? 20 and 21. Am I supposed to be reading the Network Configuration guide? I don't see the solution in the forum post.

Comment: your problem is extremely common and the solution is just a matter of using the right search terms in google. "CentOS vsftpd failed to retrieve directory listing" should provide sufficient results to resolve your issue. good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help. +1. Got me on the right path. This is what fixed it for me. http://www.gosquared.com/liquidicity/archives/936

Comment: fantastic - happy to help and thanks for linking the solution